# getting rid of extra spaces between columns

Tags: sql-server, vim

I am using a plugin called dbext in order to query a sql server database. The output of the database isn’t so flattering:

[image]

**How would I get rid of all that empty space?** Please notice that I cannot do a find/replace all because other columns have spaces inside of them.

What I have tried: I have surrounded every single datum with pipes ( | ) and tried to record a really long macro where I get rid of the empty spaces:

[image]

But that clearly wasn’t a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that’s a pretty crappy format for delimiting columns, where the separators are also scattershot amid the fields. But hopefully you can rely on the separators having 2+ spaces, and the column innards having not more than one.

Then you could add a more distinct separator, like `tab`. In fact, TSV is something of a standard among unix tools like `cut`, `paste`, `tabs`, etc.

So assuming the hopeful case above, you could convert multi-spaces (column separators) to tabs with:

```
:%s/\s\s\+/\t/g
```

Or, more generally:

```
%s/\s\{2,}/\t/g
```

Adjust the 2 up a bit if there are two spaces inside your fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your columns which have spaces inside do not have more than one space between words, then you can specify range to replace whitespace. for example this substitution.

```
:%s/\v\s{2,}/|/g
```

[Demo](http://gfycat.com/PoliticalWelltodoAsiaticgreaterfreshwaterclam#?format=gif)